# Why my two inset shadow in svg filters doesn't work?

Tags: css, svg, filter, shadow

I'm try make a two inset shadow in svg element, but it doesn't work. First shadow is overlaying on second.

This is a filter code:

```
<filter id="shadow-r-l" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">

    <feOffset dx="50" dy="50" result="offset2"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" in="offset2" result="offset-blur2"/>
    <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset-blur2" result="inverse2" />
    <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.5" result="color2" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in="color2" in2="inverse2" result="shadow2" />
    <feComposite operator="over" in="shadow2" in2="SourceGraphic" result="inset-shadow2" />

    <feOffset dx="20" dy="20" result="offset"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" in="offset" result="offset-blur"/>
    <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset-blur" result="inverse" />
    <feFlood flood-color="white" flood-opacity="0.5" result="color" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in="color" in2="inverse" result="shadow" />
    <feComposite operator="over" in="shadow" in2="SourceGraphic" result="inset-shadow" />

    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode/>
      <feMergeNode in="inset-shadow2" />
      <feMergeNode in="inset-shadow" />
    </feMerge>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is creating "inset-shadow2" result which is the source image with the upper left edge darked. The code is then creating the "inset-shadow" result which is the source image with the upper left edge lighten. The code is then using feMerge to paint "inset-shadow" result over the "inset-shadow2" result. Since the "inset-shadow" and "inset-shadow2" results take up the same space, the "inset-shadow" result will completely over write the "inset-shadow2" result. I assume you intended to combine the light and dark effects over the source image. If so, you can replace the feMerge element with multiple feComposite elements.

The code is not specifying the in attribute on the feOffset elements. This could cause problems for the second feOffset element which I assume was intended to use SourceGraphic for input.

Making these changes yields the following code...

```
<filter id="shadow-r-l" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">

    <feOffset dx="50" dy="50" in="SourceGraphic" result="offset2"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" in="offset2" result="offset-blur2"/>
    <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset-blur2" result="inverse2" />
    <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.5" result="color2" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in="color2" in2="inverse2" result="shadow2" />

    <feOffset dx="20" dy="20" in="SourceGraphic" result="offset"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" in="offset" result="offset-blur"/>
    <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset-blur" result="inverse" />
    <feFlood flood-color="white" flood-opacity="0.5" result="color" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in="color" in2="inverse" result="shadow" />

    <feComposite operator="over" in="shadow2" in2="SourceGraphic" result="inset-shadow2" />
    <feComposite operator="over" in="shadow" in2="inset-shadow2" result="inset-shadow2-shadow" />

</filter>
```